# Get the rest of the row in a max group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to acquire the most recently passed training someone has taken. To do this, I have a view that works great

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MYAPP.most_recent_training (
  employee_id, course_id, date_taken
) AS SELECT
       who.employee_id,
       course.course_id,
       MAX(sess.end_date) date_taken
  FROM employee_session_join esj
  JOIN training_session sess on sess.session_id = esj.session_id
  JOIN course_version vers on vers.version_id = sess.version_id
  JOIN course course on course.course_id = vers.course_id
  JOIN employee who on who.employee_id = esj.employee_id
  WHERE esj.active_flag = 'Y'
    AND sess.active_flag = 'Y'
    AND course.active_flag = 'Y'
    AND who.active_flag = 'Y'
    AND esj.approval_status = 5 -- successfully passed
GROUP BY who.employee_id, course.course_id
```

Okay, so my query works excellent. Here's my problem - I also need the expiry date so I know when they go out of compliance. This is stored as a number of months on the version. But I can't add `vers.valid_for_months` because it complains `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

I just want to get whatever the rest of that row is. How can I do this?

Comment: Add it to the group-by, or select it as a MAX or MIN...

Comment: But there's no guarantee it's the same value. You might take a refresher version course that's only good for 12 months, or a full version that's good for 36 months. If I add it to the group by, it would catch both of those, and I only want 1 row. (Yes, I realize it's possible you could take a 36 month, and then 2 months later take a 12 month, and that you'd be listed as being out of compliance in 12 months instead of 34 like you should, and my business users have decided that's okay - always use the most recent course taken.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this would solve your problem:

```
SELECT who.employee_id, course.course_id,
       MAX(add_months(sess.end_date, vers.valid_for_months))
```

That gets the latest end date.  If you want the end date for the last session, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT employee_id, course_id, end_date
FROM (SELECT who.employee_id, course.course_id, sess.end_date,
             row_number() over (partition by who.employee_id, course.course_id
                                order by sess.end_date
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM employee_session_join esj
      JOIN training_session sess on sess.session_id = esj.session_id
      JOIN course_version vers on vers.version_id = sess.version_id
      JOIN course course on course.course_id = vers.course_id
      JOIN employee who on who.employee_id = esj.employee_id
      WHERE esj.active_flag = 'Y'
        AND sess.active_flag = 'Y'
        AND course.active_flag = 'Y'
        AND who.active_flag = 'Y'
        AND esj.approval_status = 5 -- successfully passed
) e
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```